# ZAP Spider scan report status showing 0%

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, zap

I have configured ZAP 2.7.0 plugin with Jenkins latest version. After configuring the ZAP in Jenkins, when I try to do a spider scan, it's showing the scan status as 0%.

I don't know how to solve this issue.
This is my config:

```
Workspace   /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ZAP
Override Host    localhost
Override Port     8090
JDK     : inherit from job
System Installed ZAP installation directory
Command line arguments:   -installdir      value: /opt/zaproxy
ZAP home directory:  /opt/zaproxy
Load session:  /var/lib/jenkins/WS/ZAP/reports.session
ContextName: VolunarabityTest${BUILD_ID}
Include contest: http://myip:8080/ps
Attack mode:   starting point: http://myip:8080/ps
```

And this is the output:

> 7083 [ZAP-SpiderInitThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.spider.SpiderThread  - Starting spidering scan on Context: VolunarabityTest39 at Thu Dec 21 23:22:59 IST 2017
>   7089 [ZAP-SpiderInitThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.spider.Spider  - Spider initializing...
>
> [ZAP Jenkins Plugin] SPIDER SCAN STATUS [ 0% ]
>   [ZAP Jenkins Plugin] ALERTS COUNT [ 0 ]
>
> 7142 [ZAP-SpiderInitThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.spider.Spider  - Starting spider...
>   7220 [ZAP-SpiderThreadPool-0-thread-1] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.spider.Spider  - Spidering process is complete. Shutting down...
>   7222 [ZAP-SpiderShutdownThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.spider.SpiderThread  - Spider scanning complete:

Comment: look like the scan completed, by reading the log - does the URL accessible by ZAP? It seems to me that Zap was not able to scan at all...

Comment: I improved the formatting of the question and added two relevant tags.

Comment: It still looks like the scan completed without finding anything - notices the: `Spidering process is complete. Shutting down...` I would try to enable [debug](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQlogging) log or re-check that Zap can access the URL